# How to get user's data file after decompiling an APK?

Tags: kotlin, user-defined-functions, user-permissions, user-management

firstly I'm new to this, I wanna know which file is my data stored on 'we internet' app I'm curious to understand about which p language this app written by?

I used apktool but it failed to load additional packages.

what “classes” stand for?

I know I'm asking more questions, sorry for this, all I need is some understanding for better.

Thanks...

Comment: Your question is very incomplete, you are talking abt which data??, and if you are finding some sharedpref and database etc inside the apk decompiled by apktool then you are on the wrong way, and classes are the dex files the java/kotlin files which is apk build on

Comment: Thanks, that what I wanted to get knowledge about,

Comment: but the thing if I can't get user info, for example: I'm not talking about known information about others, I'm applying this on my info, can it be done finding readable source of user's subscription info ?

Comment: to find the subscription details , that depend on developer where he saves the data most devs save it on client side in shared pref